# Getting Github Repo Filenames Using Python

Tags: python, github, pygithub

How do you get a list of all filenames in a Github repo using Python/PyGithub without logging into a user account?

How can I use `github.Github(self.login, self.password)` if I only know about a user name, not his/her password?

Comment: Note to moderators: the question seems to me crystal clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [source code shows](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/365a0a24d3d2f06eeb4c93b4487fcfb88ae95dd0/github/Requester.py#L141-L154) that you can keep the password to '`None`' when it comes to get a GitHub object.

```py
    def __init__(self, login_or_token, password, base_url, timeout, client_id, client_secret, user_agent, per_page, api_preview):
        self._initializeDebugFeature()

        if password is not None:
            login = login_or_token
            if atLeastPython3:
                self.__authorizationHeader = "Basic " + base64.b64encode((login + ":" + password).encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8").replace('\n', '')  # pragma no cover (Covered by Authentication.testAuthorizationHeaderWithXxx with Python 3)
            else:
                self.__authorizationHeader = "Basic " + base64.b64encode(login + ":" + password).replace('\n', '')
        elif login_or_token is not None:
            token = login_or_token
            self.__authorizationHeader = "token " + token
        else:
            self.__authorizationHeader = None
```

That is [tested here](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/365a0a24d3d2f06eeb4c93b4487fcfb88ae95dd0/github/tests/Logging_.py#L70-L71):

```py
def testLoggingWithoutAuthentication(self):
   self.assertEqual(github.Github().get_user("jacquev6").name, "Vincent Jacques")
```

From there, you can get any *public* repo and list their files.

You only need to "login" for *private* repos.